# How to set merge Module installation location to Installdirectory

Tags: installation, wix, wix3.6, merge-module

I am creating a merge module for Firebird in Wix 3.6, the merge module default path goes to the window drive, Please guide me how to set permanently the merge module installation directory to the Installation directory selected by the user during installation time. Which ever path the user selects, the merge module need to be installed to the application path.

for example

User selected path\application name\app.exe (Or)

User selected path\application name\mergemodulefolder (Or)

User selected path\app.exe (Or)

User selected path\mergemodulefolder

Actually in installshield this can be done by right clicking the merge module and setting the installation location from the drop down menu

Thanks

Comment: All the files are appearing on the root of C:\, right? You probably want to add a custom action to set TARGETDIR to your install directory (usually [INSTALLDIR], by convention)

Answer (score 1):

To configure the directory the Merge Module is merged into, add the `Merge` element under the desired `Directory` element. For example:

```
<Directory Id='TARGETDIR' Name='SourceDir'>
   <Directory Id='ProgramFilesFolder'>
      <Directory Id='INSTALLFOLDER' Name='Application name'>
         <Merge SourceFile='path\to\fb.msm' />
      </Directory>
   </Directory>
</Directory>
```

Of course, you also need to add the `MergeRef` element to the Feature you want to control the install state of the Merge Modules components.